# "This page can't load Google Maps correctly."

Tags: maps

I have an active Google Cloud Platform account for the purpose of integrating the map functions into my website. Currently I have a map on my contact page (https://voltfuse.com/contact) and on my dealers page (https://voltfuse.com/dealers).

Until recently, I noticed that the map on my dealer page is no longer working, telling me that it was unable to correctly load. You can see an image of this in the attached "Broken Map.png".

It's strange because the map is working perfectly with the same API on my contact page, which can be seen on "Working Map.png".

The code for the broken page can be found here: https://codeshare.io/5w0ez7

I am wondering if anyone has any ideas as to why the map is not loading.

Thanks,

Alex

[Broken Map.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTvk7.png) [Working Map.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhsEO.png)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Google has recently imposed strict limits on the Google Maps JavaScript API. You must now enter your billing information in the Console to enable higher limits for your account. As of the date of this answer, after entering your billing information, you will receive $200 worth of free usage per month.

See more info at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing