# 2018 This page can't load Google Maps correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Sounds like duplicate? but no, this is happened since a week ago for all websites in the world that used google maps API, even I searched in google: `google maps api js fiddle`:

> http://jsfiddle.net/salman/4mtyu/
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/x4gM4/
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/2d5qum53/
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/chufol/T78Hd/
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/36tgzztv/

See? none of them working, all got message from google:

**This page can't load Google Maps correctly**

I searched in Stack Overflow, all topics are old and not solve this problem. But look like google need to an api key to work, right?

So in my web site I have api key but I got this error:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this site.

And there is a **[link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)** to enable google maps api, but after I enable api key, still have same error, any solution?

Comment: Have you enabled billing on your account with a credit card?

Comment: @geocodezip No,  I have not any credit card, Is it no longer free? Should I pay for this?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to pay, there is a credit.  But you need to enable billing with a credit card if/when you run out of the credit (the fact that it stopped working my mean you used up the credit)..

Comment: @geocodezip 1. I enabled google maps api -- 2. I enabled billing, It show maps correctly but when I type something in searchbox (places) it give me same error. why?

Comment: Did you enable the Places API?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this [maps didn't load correctly](https://churchthemes.com/page-didnt-load-google-maps-correctly/).

> This error has become a lot more common since Google Maps started requiring an API key on June 22, 2016 (after about 10 years of allowing keyless use). If you started using Google Maps on your website on or after that date then you will need to sign up for and implement an API key (older users still do not need a key).

Also, [You must now enter your billing information in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52106220/9233618).

Here is official [Google guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

> To use the Maps JavaScript API, you must get an API key which you can then add to your app or website. The API key is used to track API requests associated with your project for quota, usage, and billing. To learn more about API keys, see the API Key Best Practices and the FAQs.

Comment: I already done this, it is working but I using `libraries=places` (search box for places) when I type something I get this error again, why?

Comment: What does your developer console in browser say? Are there any errors there?

Comment: Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this site.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key Learn more: http://www.google.com/help/terms_maps.html